# Keep document height

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of elements that collapse `ondragstart`, and then uncollapse `ondragend` using Bootstrap's Collapse/Show classes

What I'm running into is that ***if the user is scrolled far enough down the page that removing that element's height makes the bottom of the page higher than the bottom of the viewport***, the viewport is forced to scroll up to make up for it, which cancels the drag and calls `ondragend`, which then un-collapses the element and resizes the document to where it was, making it look like nothing happened.

My question is: **How would I force the document/body to always be tall enough to prevent the auto-scroll?**

Or, is it possible to somehow maintain the drag even through the scroll?

I have the `min-height` of the `body` set to `100vh`, but that doesn't account for a page starting out to be taller than the viewport anyway.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertgreenstreet/jcodbv5n/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your sections are wrapped by a `form` element.

```js
<form>
  <section</section>
  <section</section>
  <section</section>
  <section</section>
</form>
```

What if, before you collapse any cards, you detect the form's actual height and force it to maintain that height using `element.style.height`?

Something like this:

```js
function setHeight(element) {
  element.style.height = element.offsetHeight + "px";
}

function clearHeight(element) {
  element.style.height = "";
}
```

I haven't tried it, but I suspect it will do what you need.

Here's a little demo, it seems to work just fine.

```js
function setHeight(element) {
  element.style.height = element.offsetHeight + "px";
}

function clearHeight(element) {
  element.style.height = "";
}

const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const el2 = document.getElementById('el2');
const el3 = document.getElementById('el3');

function collapse () {
  setHeight(wrapper);
  el2.classList.add('collapse');
  el3.classList.add('collapse');
  setTimeout( () => clearHeight(wrapper), 2000);
}

function expand () {
  clearHeight(wrapper)
  el2.classList.remove('collapse');
  el3.classList.remove('collapse');
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
#el1, #el2, #el3, #el4 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: white;
}
.el {
  height: 40px;
}
.collapse {
  height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="collapse();">Collapse el 2 and 3</button>
  <button onclick="expand();">Expand el 2 and 3</button>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="el1" class="el">el1</div>
    <div id="el2" class="el">el2</div>
    <div id="el3" class="el">el3</div>
    <div id="el4" class="el">el4</div>
    wrapper
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The idea is to have the sections shrink in order to be able to see more of the list when dragging/sorting, so keeping the space there among/between the sections themselves won't work, but I'm wondering if I could maybe use this same idea to force the height of the body to be what it was before the rest of the `dragstart` actions, or at least force it to be viewport height + collapsed section's original height

Comment: @RGreenstreet Forcing the body height might work, as well. It looks like your sections are inside one form element, so forcing the height of the `<form>` ought to work, also.

Comment: I just added this and it pretty much works: `
     fullForm.style.height = (fullForm.scrollHeight) + 'px';` and then in the `ondragend` set it back to blank as you suggested. However now if one of the questions gets dragged into a section that's taller than the section it came from, the 'Add Section' button is floating atop everything at the bottom left until the `ondragend` resets the height: https://imgur.com/a/ls0N8Ns. I'll work on that separately.

Comment: @RGreenstreet I think you want `offsetHeight`, not `scrollHeight`. `offsetHeight` is the element's height "including vertical padding and borders". `scrollHeight` is the height of just the element's content.

Comment: Updated to use that, thanks. Still have the floating link, but I'll call it a day on this for now.